# How to use i18n inside a mongoose schema validation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, internationalization, i18next

Im using i18n in my node app with 2 languages (en and de). When I use it inside controllers it works as expected but when I am using it inside my mongoose schema, I always get the translation for en, even if the language is set to German.

i18n.config.js:

```
const { I18n } = require('i18n');
const path = require('path');

const i18n = new I18n({
    locales: ['en', 'de'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    directory: path.join('./', 'locales')
});

module.exports = i18n;
```

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, i18n.__('noEmail')],
        validate: {
            name: 'ValidationError',
            validator: validator.isEmail,
            message: i18n.__n('noEmail'),
        },
```

I have 2 files in locales/de.json and locales/en.json and im always retrieving the value inside the en.json file. I couldnt find any answers anywhere. What am I doing wrong? Thanks